# Why android studio 1.3 give warning to override supper class methods for Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I have updated Android Studio 1.3 and used `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`. But for every activity lifecycle methods calling it is showing an warning that tells "Override method should call super.onCreate()". I don't know why it is happening. Is it a bug for new release?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug, you can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174964). There is no workaround atm. If you are calling the super class, just ignore it.

***Edit***:

The issue has been fixed in Android Studio preview 2. See [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio13preview2available)

Comment: Ok now got it, just ignore it.

Comment: yep, sorry I forgot to add *it* at the end